# Using em instead of pt

Tags: css, scaling, font-size

I was reading [Web Content Accessibility Guidelines 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/WAI-WEBCONTENT-19990505/) (sec 3.4, page 13) where it says to use em rather than pt.

My question is that the images that you develop for a web site are done in terms of pixels. So if you are using relative sizing for them, the browser will have to scale them. Is there any good techniques to ensure that the pictures do not get too distorted (i.e. bits become too blurred etc)? Alternatively if you chose not to scale the images, is there any techniques to ensure that the layout does not get corrupted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you have a read of [Responsive Web Design](http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design) by Ethan Marcotte. He talks about a technique of not specifying any height/width on your `img` tags, and instead set the `max-width` to 100%:

```
img {
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

In fact, this will work for any fixed-width elements like videos/flash etc

IE6 and below don't support max-width properly, so you can set `width: 100%;` instead, which is a basic workaround.

The book also explains how to use `AlphaImageLoader` to improve image scaling in IE7 and below.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the bottom of this [sizing study](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/em_images.html) done to compare `px` to `em` sizing techniques as images grow larger/render at lower percentages.

Under the section titled "Information", there is [even more](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/em_images_extra.html) to look at.

It appears you just have to keep playing with the number after the decimal point, and get those `F5` muscles stretched and limber. `;)`

Answer (score 1):

It generally does not make sense to specify image dimensions in `em`. It would not improve anything and would just make images blurred. Use `em` for text only, and let images be kept in their original size. Additionally, you can use `IMG {max-width: 100%}` if don't want images to overflow their container on narrow browser-window sizes.